# Voltage swings at my house

Tags: electrical

Two out of 3 Bromic tungsten Infrared patio heaters sparked and completely burned the connector wire at teh bulb.

Bromic engineers initially said the units were faulty and replaced them but later said the units burned up due to voltage or amp swings.

I asked what an acceptable voltage swing is and they said -5 to +5. I asked how to measure that and what to do if the vltage swing is too high. They said ask my electrician which i did and he said he did not know.

I am afraid to turn on the heaters because Bromic said they will not replace them again and the units are $700 per unit. HELP!!

Comment: What part of the world are you in? What is the recommended voltage for these units? Have you had any other strange problems? Can you get a multimeter to check the voltage in your regular receptacles?

Comment: Can you get a $20 "Kill-a-Watt" monitoring device, and plug it into your receptacles?  I'm real keen on knowing if your power has a high and/or low voltage.  It's a common and very serious problem where half your circuits have voltage below 120 and the other half have voltage *above* 120, and this teeter-totters back and forth depending on the loads at the moment.  Are you noticing anything else weird about power in the house?

Comment: +-10% is what my power company considers normal.  My daily swings are normally within 5% but that is more than 5v, this sounds like a crock of bull to me if the voltage drops a resistive element will produce less heat and not cause an excess current , a higher voltage would produce more heat and could cause problems but over voltage is rare compared to under voltage with a properly operating system. my measurements show voltage dips regularly but rarely do I note over voltage of more than 3% under voltage of 7-10% many times a day is normal.